# Map network server using cifs: manual mount works, fstab fails

Tags: server, mount, samba, fstab, cifs

Been trying to setup a permanent mount for my institutional network server from my work-ubuntu 16.04 (dual boot windows - ubuntu). This has worked before. I have followed the many fine tutorials on this - for instance [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountWindowsSharesPermanently).

When I mount manually it works - i am asked for sudo password and then the institutional password. I type:
`sudo mount -t cifs -o username=myusername$institution.domain,vers=1.0 //institution.domain/myusername /media/networkfolder`

However, when I try to setup in fstab using a credentials file (or also without) it fails. I have this line:

`//institution.domain/myusername /media/networkfolder cifs credentials=/home/me/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,uid=1000,vers=1.0`

The .smbcredentials file reads:

```
username=myusername
password=mypassword
```

(variations that fails are username=myusername$institution.domain and also tried including the line domain=institution.domain).

When I look into the running `/var/log/kern.log` I do not find any obvious hints.

Comment: Did you also try replacing `institution.domain` by the IP adress?

Comment: The IP is changing so this is not possible.